# How do I create a bitset from binary string?

Tags: c++, char, bitset

I have a binary string in a file that looks like

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001100100101101100110000110100110110111000010100110110110110111000011001000010110010010001100010010001010010010100001011001100010100001100100011011101`

(which is 256 bits). Can I set this string as the value of a `bitset<256>` really quickly?

Currently I am doing

```
for (int t = sizeof(c) - 1; t > 0; t--) {
   if (c[t] == '1') {
      b |= 1;
   }
   b <<= 1;
}
b >>= 1;
```

But my results are incorrect.

Comment: Are you sure `t=sizeof(c)-1` is correct? What is `sizeof(c)`?

Comment: Yes, there's a constructor for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can I set this string as the value of a bitset<256> really quickly?

Yes, you can just use the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset), the example below is taken right from the document and works for `256` as well:

```
std::string bit_string = "110010";
std::bitset<8> b3(bit_string);       // [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0]

std::cout << b3.to_string() << std::endl ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not access the  by indices directly? like..

```
b[t] = c[t] - '0';
```